# Detecting if a custom file icon was set in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, icons, nsurl

I wrote an app that sets a custom icon for some files, but as the creation of such an icon is quite expensive I'd like to test if a custom icon was already set before. With custom icon I mean an icon that isn't the default icon set by OS X. In particular, I can have different icons for different files having the same type.

I already tried checking `[NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLCustomIconKey,NSURLEffectiveIconKey,nil] error:nil]`, but the object associated with `NSURLEffectiveIconKey` is always non-nil and `NSURLCustomIconKey` seems to be nil even if I call `[NSURL setResourceValue:myNonNilImage forKey:NSURLCustomIconKey error:nil]`.

Calling `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:myImage forFile:myFilename options:0]` by the way seems the only way to change the icon displayed in the Finder.

Comment: Show us your real code to get a better idea of what's going on

Comment: By now I call `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:myImage forFile:myFilename options:0]` every time I load a file for which I want to set the custom icon. The problem is how to know if this file was already set an icon so that I can avoid resetting it.

Comment: Yes. You pasted some fragments of code in the question, which you say you tried. Please post the full code of what you tried so we can get a decent idea.

Comment: At the moment I'm using `if ([[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:myFilename] representations] count]>4) [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:myImage forFile:myFilename options:0];` because apparently myImage only has 4 representations. But this seems to be a nasty workaround to me.

Comment: That is a very nasty workaround indeed. I wouldn't dare trust it myself

Comment: So I'm not making myself very clear: what you're basically saying is that the `NSURL` API for this is buggy. I'd like to see your code that uses it just to see if there's anything obviously wrong.

Comment: I tried `NSLog(@"%@",[fileURL resourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLCustomIconKey,NSURLEffectiveIconKey, nil] error:nil]); NSLog(@"%d %d",[fileURL setResourceValue:image forKey:NSURLCustomIconKey error:nil],[fileURL setResourceValue:image forKey:NSURLEffectiveIconKey error:nil]); NSLog(@"%@",[fileURL resourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLCustomIconKey,NSURLEffectiveIconKey,nil] error:nil]);` but this always prints a dictionary with NSURLEffectiveIconKey as the only entry, the string "1 1", and the same dictionary again. Using `nil`instead of `image` doesn't help.

Comment: Well at least attempt some error handling to see if that reports anything useful/interesting!

Comment: But there are no errors since both method calls return 1, right?

Comment: I'm thinking primarily of the various setter methods you're calling. Those calls might well be failing without your knowing about it!

Comment: I was talking about those setter methods inside the NSLog ... They both return 1 as I pointed out earlier. Anyway, I tried passing an &error to all methods I mention in the comment above, and all of them were null.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas I'm afraid. File a radar complaining he API is broken and hope it's fixed in 10.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSURLCustomIconKey always returns nil because support for this key is not implemented. This essential bit of information is mentioned in the header but not in the NSURL documentation. Until it is supported one way to get this information is through deprecated File Manager methods:

```
- (BOOL)fileHasCustomIcon:(NSString *)path {
    FSRef ref;
    FSCatalogInfo info;

    if (FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8 *)[path fileSystemRepresentation], &ref, NULL) == noErr) {
        if (FSGetCatalogInfo(&ref, kFSCatInfoFinderInfo, &info, NULL, NULL, NULL) == noErr) {
            FileInfo *fileInfo = (FileInfo *)(&info.finderInfo);
            return (fileInfo->finderFlags & kHasCustomIcon) != 0;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/setIcon%3aforFile%3aoptions%3a) says that `setIcon:forFile:options:` returns YES if it was successful.

With that information you can simply switch a NSUserDefault boolean. Here some code I used:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"iconImageSaved"]) {
    if ([[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:myImage forFile:myFilename options:0])
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"iconImageSaved"];
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this solution won't work for me as I would have to set a default for every file I want to set the icon for, and the icon could have already been set on another Mac.