# How to get an alias icon WITHOUT the arrow?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Using `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:path]` for an alias file returns an icon image with an arrow.

How can I instead get the icon without the arrow?

I don't want this arrow:

[image]

Comment: Just an idea: get the icon for the original file?

Comment: This works but only if the alias has no custom icon.

Comment: Can't you use the custom icon if the alias has a custom icon?

Comment: How to get the custom icon of a file? NSURLCustomIconKey is not implemented in Cocoa ([url getResourceValue:&ret forKey:NSURLCustomIconKey error:nil] returns always nil). From the doc:  "The custom icon assigned to the resource, if any (Currently not implemented, value type NSImage)"

Comment: Why not to use the Quicklook preview image for the file as described in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815458/get-quicklook-preview-image-for-file

Comment: See [Detecting if a custom file icon was set in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017927/detecting-if-a-custom-file-icon-was-set-in-cocoa)